# Microsoft Graph - Longterm Access to OneDrive API (Refresh Token?)

Tags: api, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, token, onedrive

Currently, I am using the Token Authentication Flow to connect MS Graph OneDrive API to my application. ([Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)) It works, yet I have to use Postman to get a new authentication token after 30min-2h (I'm not sure about the exact timeframe). I need to be able to access the OneDrive API for a longer period of time (multiple months) without having to authenticate again and again.

In the documentation, the also speak about the Code Flow ([Link to Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)). Yet I don't receive a refresh token nor do I know how to set it up for longterm access.

I wrote an application in python that uploads files from OneDrive to another application.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer but it could help you arrive to solution via another route. In my case, I was following the process presented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/xamarin?tutorial-step=3#get-user-details), which really then lets user choose if they would like be remembered on the device. Then token gets stored and the method attempts silent authentication before requiring interactive login. So basically you get to use Graph API seamlessly.

Obviously, the authentication still needs to happen but perhaps you could reuse the token for direct requests?